# NativeScript angular App Xcode build Error

Tags: xcode, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to build my app in Xcode and I keep getting the following error:

```
ld: framework not found FLAnimatedImage
```

In my app, I am using a gif plugin for this error I got solution put this line of code `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES`

In the build file but still giving the same error how can I solve the above error or any alternative solution. Environment- Xcode 10.3 , NativeScript 6 , angular 8

Comment: Did you try a clean build after updating the build config?

Comment: yes I did clean build still same error